# Does this algebraic surface have a name?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Does this algebraic surface have a name, or is otherwise known?

$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 - 2 x^2 y^2 + 2 y^2 z^2 + 2 z^2 x^2 - 4 z^2 = 0 $

Here's a (somewhat squished along the z-axis) image:

[image: surface]

Comment: In general, one gives names to projective surfaces (given as zeroes of homogeneous polynomials) and yours is not one. A smooth quartic surface in projective 3-space is called a K3 surface and some of the special ones with singularities are called Kummer surfaces.

Comment: I would note that every variable is raised to an even power (and hence positive).  A possibly related surface would be found from the substitution $x^2 \to x$, $y^2 \to y$ and $z^2 \to z$ for positive variables.

Comment: If it as not yet a name, why not call it "Roswell surface" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie based on your suggestion, I suspect that there are other, related surfaces, waiting to be discovered. A "Roswell body surface", "Roswell arm", "Roswell leg", etc. Once those surfaces have been characterized, SETI can start searching for the corresponding powers and coefficients of $x,y,z$...

Comment: @JeanMarie I was going to go with [cat hamburger pillow surface](https://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com/cat-burger-pillow/) but that seemed a little long.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork With that substitution, it's a quadric surface, specifically an elliptic cone. This surface is clearly more complicated than an elliptic cone.